# update validation In laravel with unique check in multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In laravel with unique check in multiple tables, I do this for create new field:

```
 //store function

'slug' => 'required|unique:articles,slug|unique:zones,slug
```

It works well.

but what can I do for update?

I test this:

```
public function update(request $request, Sight $sight)
     {
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'slug' => 'unique:articles,slug,'.$sight->id.'|unique:zones,slug,'.$sight->id.'
```

But it allowed duplicate slug.

Comment: You have to pass the article id not the Sight one and the same for zone.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique), the way to do this is:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'slug' => [
         Rule::unique('articles')->ignore($sight->id, "slug"),
         Rule::unique('zones')->ignore($sight->id, "slug")
      ]
]);
```

Comment: You have to pass the article id not the Sight one and the same for zone isn't it ?

Comment: @Maraboc depends what you need to do. The original validation requires the same slug field to be unique in both tables so there's no reason to believe that this case would be different, e.g. if you want a unique slug across different tables. This is up to OP to know though

Comment: Yes i agree but in the doc `Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check` and the example they give is this `'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')` in users table ignore the given `$user->id` same here in articles table ignore `someArticleId` !!

Comment: @Maraboc let's let OP decide if this is what they really want. You can answer the question as well if you think you have a solution which is what OP really needs and/or is more useful to everyone

Comment: this doesn't work. You need to pass second parameter to the unique() function